# iOS Black bar issue when using auto layout

Tags: ios-autolayout

I am using Auto layout in my app. I have added constraints on my view. It is working fine in all iPad simulator and iPhone 4s. But when I run this app on iPhone 5s or greater it is showing black bar on left and right side of the screen.
[image: Here is screen shot of my xib]

[image: on iPhone 6s]

Comment: 1. Please add a picture of your Storyboard, showing the auto layout.

Comment: 2. Please add a picture of this "black bar" you speak of.

Comment: What are the constraints of scrollview, may be there are conflicting constraints and could be Xcode is ignoring few constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also faced this same issue, when I am converting my iPad app to Universal app.

**Ref below Image: You can see Main Interface is not set**
[image]

After that add **LaunchScreen.storyboard** to your project if not exists.

**Ref this Image: Goto your ProjectName-Info.plist add following key**
[image]

```
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>
```

Now run the project

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Storyboard.  Click on the UIView.  Click on the third icon in the auto-layout stuff on the bottom.  Now click all of the red line things in the top (stuff circled in pink in below picture) to be set at zero.
[image]

EDIT: another possibility is that you have constrained the size of the view in some way. I would try doing reset to suggested constraints, and then set the constraints illustrated above for the background (grey) view so it fills everything up, but do not set it to have an explicit size.

EDIT 2: If that grey thing in the background is a UIImage, I bet the issue is that it is in Aspect Fit. Change the content mode to Aspect Fill and I think it should work.

Comment: Do you have any code that resizes anything? And please post screenshots of what he problem looks like and of your autolayout stuff.

Comment: No there is no any code for setting constraints. I have used only auto layout. I have added screen shot in my question please check.

Comment: See edit. I think you explicitly constrained hubiese size

Comment: Ok check again, I think that the issue is that Ccbg.png or whatever is aspect fit not aspect fill! :)

Comment: Still same issue, This is working fine in all iPad and iPhone 4s but iPhone 5s and greater it is showing black Bar